# Iterating through an array on scroll in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have used Lettering.js to create a collection of `<span>` elements with class `"char*"`, `*` signifying an integer in this example. I created an array of these elements as follows:

```
var characterArray = $("[class^='char']");
```

I have used the Fisher-Yates Shuffle Algorithm below:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var m = array.length, t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle…
    while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
    }

    return array;
}
```

To manipulate `characterArray` as follows:

```
    var disappearArray = shuffle(characterArray);
```

So I currently have an array containing a randomly ordered collection of elements that I want to iterate through on scroll incrementally. My goal is to have a `<span>` element contained in the array `display:none` every time the user scrolls, until all `<span>` elements in the array are not displaying.

I have tried:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $.each(disappearArray, function(i, val) {
        $(val).addClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

but on scroll all the elements are set to `display:none`.

How can I set this to happen on an incremental basis?

Comment: Why do u use so many classes? Idea of .class is they have sth in common. U can consider IDs or at least add a classname 'char' and use selector accordingly.

Comment: The [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com) jquery plugin returns spans with that class naming convention.

Comment: can u have it add 'char char*'?

Answer (score 0):

$(window).scrollTop() will return a value of how much you have scrolled, so you might consider some amount of scrolled pixels, for each span. makes sense? :)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrolled  = $(window).scrollTop();

    $.each(disappearArray, function(i, val) {
        scrolled > i * disappearArray.length?
        $(val).addClass("hidden") : $(val).removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

Something similar :) Hope it helps you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! On line 5, `dissapearArray` should be `disappearArray`